# How do I force the x-axis to stay at 0 in OxyPlot?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I am creating an application in OxyPlot. I would like for the minimum point on the x-axis to remain at zero, while the maximum point continues to grow as new data is populated on the graph. Currently what is happening, is that the graph seems to look like a sliding window instead, something like:

**Here is what the graph looks like now:**

```
[------------]
0           100
```

and 25 seconds later...

```
[------------]
25          125
```

**Here is what I actually want:**

```
[-------------]
0            100
```

and 25 seconds later...

```
[-------------]
0            125
```

I looked into some of the methods/properties of the `LinearAxis` (which I am using to define my x-axis), and the closest thing I could find was the `AbsoluteMinimum` property, which I've set to `0`. Setting the `AbsoluteMinimum` property, did not seem to do the trick however. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I have same question. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565360/oxyplot-axis-locking-center-when-mouse-wheel/41589285?noredirect=1#comment70415810_41589285

Comment: @黃柏森 Yes, that's the same problem I am having. It looks like someone figured it out for your question, I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

I added that property in my XAML code:

```
<oxy:Plot.Axes>
   <oxy:LinearAxis  Style="{DynamicResource PlotAxisStyle}" Position="Bottom" Minimum="1" />
   <oxy:LinearAxis Style="{DynamicResource PlotAxisStyle}" Position="Left"  Minimum="0" />
</oxy:Plot.Axes>
```

This works fine for me, but I am only using values up to 100 in my x-axis (Bottom position)

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to give this a try and will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Minimum property, and set its equal 0.